# Tree kind implementation via map

Tags: c++, dictionary, tree

I wan't to code Tree kind implementation via map container.

Input

```
> S Hugo Laura
> S Hugo Jasper
> S Laura Helena
> S Jasper Maria
> S Laura Elias
> S Helena Sofia
> P Hugo
```

Output

```
Hugo
..Laura
....Helena
......Sofia
....Elias
..Jasper
....Maria
```

I've already have split function that splits Hugo and Laura into variables. But how should I achieve Output kind result via map container. Should I use some kind recursion or map in the map in the map which sounds weird to me ( endless map).
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Usually we do the opposite--implement a map via a tree. As it stands, your question isn't clear.

Comment: What is the reason you want to use maps for this?

Comment: I'm allowed to use map or vector or both only. The task is to practice STL-containers.

Comment: That still doesn't clarify your question. Are you making a 2-3 tree? A binary search tree? A red black tree? What code have you written so far and where did you get stuck?

Comment: None code yet, I'm just brainstorming the way to achieve the output as shown. That's why I'm asking how to achieve the output using map. Or what should I use?

If I use map for example:
`std::map<std::string,std::string> Store;
 Store["Hugo"]="Laura"`

But how can I pair Laura to Helena and so on.

Comment: You can also use `std::list` instead of `std::map`.  Looks like each node should have a `std::list` container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one possible solution, using `multimap`. You don't have to copy it, but feel free to make your own using this as an example. Multimap allows to have duplicate keys which you can query with `equal_range` method. By using map value as the next node in combination with recursive function is possible to produce the exact result required:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

void explore (std::multimap<std::string, std::string> const &tree, std::string const &key, int level) 
{
    level+=2;
    auto range = tree.equal_range(key);
    for (auto it = range.first; it != range.second; ++it)
    {
        std::cout << std::string(level, '.') << it->second << std::endl;
        explore(tree, it->second, level);
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::multimap<std::string, std::string> tree = 
    {
        { "Hugo", "Laura" },
        { "Hugo", "Jasper" },
        { "Laura", "Helena" },
        { "Jasper", "Maria" },
        { "Laura", "Elias" },
        { "Helena", "Sofia" }
    };

    std::string root = "Hugo";
    std::cout << root << std::endl;
    explore(tree, root, 0);

    return 0;
}
```

https://ideone.com/HywQo9

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. I never used multimap before, what is the main difference?

Comment: Also in the same task I need to print int value of Hugos "subcategories", which is in total 6 and longest "node-link" which is 4.

Comment: std::map keys are unique std::multimap could have duplicate keys. As for other tasks, the data is there you just need to tweak it and print it.

Comment: Yeah. Thanks, that helped a lot!